# Insert marker at specified position in svg with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, svg

I want to insert the marker at specified position in svg element, like for a rectangle I want to insert the marker at any width of rectangle not at start,mid end.

Answer (score 0):

Normal SVG markers (`<marker>`) can only be placed at the vertices of paths and some shapes.  If you want them placed at other points you need create separate marker shapes and position them yourself.

The upcoming SVG 2 standard will allow more options for placement, but those new features aren't supported by browsers yet.